# WYSIWYG web scraping/crawling setup using Javascript/html5?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping, wysiwyg, web-crawler

My goal is to allow less experienced people to setup the required parameters needed to scrape some information from a website.

The idea is that a user enters an URL, after which this URL is loaded in a frame. The user should then be able to select text within this frame, which should give me enough information to scrape this information again when this specific text changes dynamically.

The question is, if it's even possible to detect what part of the source of an external site corresponds to the selection of the user in a frame?

If not, are there any alternatives ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: The short answer is no.  If you don't control the content in the iframe, there's not much you can do to interact with it.  However, you could make a bookmarklet that does something like you're describing, or a browser plugin.  The part I'm not completely following is the "which should give me enough information to scrape this information again when this specific text changes dynamically" part.

Comment: @georgemandis make your comment an answer. it is a complete answer actualluy. ;)

Comment: @Geogermandis, if I copy the source and make internal links and image sources external to run this in a frame that I do own, that would allow me to do what I want?

Comment: you might be able to, but I'm not exactly sure what you want to do :).  @rahim, good idea - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. If you don't control the content in the iframe, there's not much you can do to interact with it.

However, you could make a bookmarklet that does something like you're describing, or a browser plugin.

Comment: I will ask a follow up question on a later date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There have been attempts at visual based scrapers before, but they rapidly become more cumbersome and complex to learn than writing code. With a few abstractions (a function to scrape, a function to select a table by ID and convert it to an array etc) you can make something that is still suitable by beginners.